# Behaviour space simultaneous simulations error

Tags: netlogo

I'm using behaviour space to run 100 simulations.

The problem is when I try to run more than 1 simulation at a time, some of the variables don't seem to be cleared properly.

Here is an example output: 
[image]

Each simulation (the first column is the run number) has a variable (in the last column) reset to 0. It then adds a number between 0 and 5 until it eventually maxes out at 25. Since it only runs 2 ticks, the max result should be 10...

However as can be seen, the next simulation occasionally starts out with the max value for the variable. Is this a glitch or has someone seen something like it before? (perhaps the parallel processing isn't properly working?)

**Problem/Solution**
I had a setup function that initialized certain variables, THEN used `clear-all`, and then created turtles using the variables at the beginning. By looking at the results, it looks like rather than the new turtles being initialized... they somehow retained values from the previous simulation (with the score property already maxed). The problem was fixed by repositioning clear-all at the top. Note that this only caused problems when running multiple simulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems possible that you are running into https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/105.

Are you calling `clear-all` at the start of your `setup` procedure?

Comment: That looks like it. So the problem is that I'm using clear-all without setting the random seed?

Comment: You _should_ be calling `clear-all` at the start of `setup`. The problem would occur if you _don't_ call it. I don't think the random seed is involved in this case. But maybe I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: I was calling clear-all a few lines after the start of setup, I'll try moving it to the top and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

Interface globals (e.g., sliders) do not have a default value (unfortunately!) so `clear-all` does not affect them.  This means you can run into problems if your BehaviorSpace experiments (i) do not specify values for *all* interface globals and (ii) describe simulations that alter the values of some interface globals.  In this case, one foreground run can affect the next foreground run, even though you call `clear-all` in your `setup`.

If you instructed BehaviorSpace to call your `setup`, which includes a call to `clear-all`, this is the only way I see for your problem to arise.  If it is something else, I hope you will post a description.

Comment: You're right. (See https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/105#issuecomment-97534661.) I just didn't think @Alter's variable was an interface global because the expression in the spreadsheet starts with `sum [sco`...

Comment: posted a description; your and nicolas' answer pointed me in the right direction, it seems it was a variable initialization problem related to clear-all (if i could accept both, i would). The catch is that local variables were being cleared, I'm not sure exactly how this works... but correcting the order fixed the problem.